# Cannot get Universal Links to work

Tags: ios, ios-universal-links

I know it's been asked before, and I've tried everything I can find here and in the Apple forums and in various how-to websites, but I still missing something, and I'm at my wit's end.  I hope someone can spot a mistake somewhere.

I’m working with XCode 7.3.1 and iOS 9.3.2 on the iPhone 6S.

Member Center App IDs 
ID:  com.hotelplanner.hotelplanner

App ID has Assoc. Domains enabled

Development Provisioning Profile with Assoc. Domains enabled
iOS Team Provisioning Profile: com.hotelplanner.hotelplanner

My selected Debug Provisioning Profile in XCode Build Settings matches the one with App Domains enabled in the member center.

Xcode Capabilities
Associated Domains
  Applinks:www.hotelplanner.com

Xcode entitlements

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>com.apple.developer.associated-domains</key>
    <array>
        <string>applinks:www.hotelplanner.com</string>
    </array>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Curl download of apple-app-site-association
Titan:app nancysmithwp$ curl -v https://www.hotelplanner.com/.well-known/apple-app-site-association
*   Trying 69.56.156.14...
* Connected to www.hotelplanner.com (69.56.156.14) port 443 (#0)
* TLS 1.2 connection using TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
* Server certificate: *.hotelplanner.com
* Server certificate: Symantec Class 3 Secure Server CA - G4
* Server certificate: VeriSign Class 3 Public Primary Certification Authority - G5

```
> GET /.well-known/apple-app-site-association HTTP/1.1
> Host: www.hotelplanner.com
> User-Agent: curl/7.43.0
> Accept: *
> 
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Content-Type: application/json
< Last-Modified: Wed, 29 Jun 2016 14:05:46 GMT
< Accept-Ranges: bytes
< ETag: "f35d6255fd2d11:0"
< Vary: Accept-Encoding,User-Agent
< Server: HOTELPLANNER.COM
< P3P: CP="NOI DSP COR LAW NID CUR ADMa OUR DELa IND PHY ONL UNI PUR COM NAV STA"
< Date: Wed, 29 Jun 2016 17:24:51 GMT
< Content-Length: 169
< 
{
  "applinks": {
    "apps": [],
    "details": [
      {
        "appID": "M57RZA2QX5.com.hotelplanner.hotelplanner",
        "paths":[ "/Hotels" ]
     }
    ]
  }
}
```

I’ve set my iOS Deployment Target to 9.0 so should not need it signed.

The validation tool at https://search.developer.apple.com/appsearch-validation-tool, given the url www.hotelplanner.com/Hotels/2446-in-Nassau-Bahamas.html says app site association file passed.  Deep link failed with ‘Could not extract required information for deep links.’

The same link in notes always opens in Safari.  A long press on the link gives me no options.

myAppDelegate has application:continueUserActivity:restorationHandler
 implemented.

```
-(BOOL) application:(UIApplication*) application continueUserActivity:(nonnull NSUserActivity *)userActivity restorationHandler:(nonnull void (^)(NSArray * _Nullable))restorationHandler{

    if (userActivity.activityType == NSUserActivityTypeBrowsingWeb){ 
        NSLog(@"continueUserActivity");
    }
    return NO;
}
```

There are no errors in the console when I launch the app on my device.

Edited to add:
I implemented webcredentials to see if I could get any more insight, and I get an error in the callback that www.hotelplanner.com isn't in my entitlements, but it is there, and the target checkbox for it is set.   Also, if I leave the first parameter NULL, so that it uses the domain from my entitlement file, I get the error 'No domain provided.'

[image: entitlements]

Comment: Do you get any sort of error in the Xcode device logs the first time you install (delete it first and then reinstall)? Anything like this? `Sep 21 14:27:01 Derricks-iPhone swcd[2044] <Notice>: 2015-09-21 02:27:01.878907 PM [SWC] ### Rejecting URL 'https://examplecustomdomain.com/apple-app-site-association' for auth method 'NSURLAuthenticationMethodServerTrust': -6754/0xFFFFE59E kAuthenticationErr`

Comment: The only thing I see in the device logs are a crash from a week ago.  Nothing seems to be printed when the app is installed.

Comment: Hmmm...we might be talking about different device logs because I'd be very surprised if you could find _anything_ there from a week ago! Here's what I'm hoping to see: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rHQZy_WFdEs

Comment: Thank you for that link!  I was unaware of the bottom half of that window.  There is quite a lot there.  I unstalled, rebooted, and reinstalled the app, but there's nothing like your example in the logs.  It did show some errors, particularly SecTrustEvaluate, but I'll have to rerun it a few times again tomorrow to see if they're related to my app.

Comment: Yes...those logs definitely fly by quickly! It seems that somehow the authentication loop isn't getting closed fully, so either the file isn't getting requested OR the request is failing. The other thing to check is that the .entitlements file is added to your build target. Sometimes it isn't the first time

Comment: I've been comparing logs before and after implementing Associated Domains and I don't see anything that stands out that could be related to trying to retrieve the app-app-site-association file.   Would it always be logged if it were being requested, and if yes, why wouldn't it be?  The only thing I see regarding entitlements is 'securityd[99] <Error>:  secTaskDiagnoseEntitlements MISSING keychain entitlements: no stored taskRef found'  but I cannot tell if that is related to my app or not.

Comment: The message above would only be shown if Universal Links were enabled but the `apple-app-site-association` file couldn't be retrieved due to permissions issues. I'd suggest running through [this guide](https://blog.branch.io/how-to-setup-universal-links-to-deep-link-on-apple-ios-9) and double checking every step to make sure nothing weird happened

Answer (score 2):

I finally filed my first technical support assistance request with Apple and was able to get this resolved.   Under Code Signing, the entries under Any SDK were empty.  I deleted these entries and everything works like a charm.

[image: Bad Code Signing Entitlements Section]

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue in the past, which appeared to be an XCode bug. I had been using the same device to test builds on prior to implementing universal links, and once I implemented them, they did not work. By uninstalling the app & reinstalling it, I was then able to get the links to work.

My assumption is that the link is created in the OS upon installation of the app.

Answer (score 0):

I have same problem with your situation and I solved.
App Search API Validation Tool(https://search.developer.apple.com/appsearch-validation-tool) from apple, I got ACTION REQUIRED
Could not extract required information for deep links. Learn how to implement the recommended in Deep Link but it works.

change "paths":[ "/Hotels" ] to "paths":[ "/Hotels/*" ].

I hope it works.

Comment: I just have an empty method there now.-(BOOL) application:(UIApplication*) application continueUserActivity:(nonnull NSUserActivity *)userActivity restorationHandler:(nonnull void (^)(NSArray * _Nullable))restorationHandler{

    if (userActivity.activityType == NSUserActivityTypeBrowsingWeb){ 
        NSLog(@"continueUserActivity");
    }
 return NO;
}

Comment: If you run universal link, you have to rebuild your app and test again. please test again after rebuild your project.

Comment: You need to return YES to continueUserActivity in order to get links to work. This according to https://developer.apple.com/library/content/qa/qa1916/_index.html